# How to convert a variable to string format? KSH shell scripting

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh

I am trying to convert a variable to a string format so I can use java runsql utility to insert its value into a database later. The database needs the value to be in a char format, hence string.

This is a dumbed down version of my code so I can get to the heart of what I'm asking -

```
#!/bin/ksh -x
value1=2018-01-01
value2=2018-02-01

mystring=$value1,$value2
echo $mystring

stringify=${'value1'},${'value2'})
echo $stringify
```

What happens is I get no output for stringify or depending on how I switch up the arrangement of the symbols I get the literal string `'value1'` or `'value2'`.

What am I doing wrong? I feel like this is very simple, maybe I've just been staring at it too long, I dunno.

Comment: Why do you have the quotes in `${'value1'}`? What are they intended to do? Showing your expected output explicitly (*My desired output is X, my actual output is Y*) would make this question considerably easier to understand.

Comment: ...to be very, very clear -- every single variable you have here **already is a string**. `mystring` is a string. `value1` and `value2` contain strings. This code contains no non-string variables whatsoever -- so when you say "convert a variable to string format", it's not at all clear what you're asking for.

Comment: @WalterA OP's intended use for SQL suggests they want to quote the value.

Comment: Thanks @Vasan, missed that, deleted my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just escape quote like this:

```
mystring=\'$value1\',\'$value2\'
```

Output:

> $ echo $mystring
>
> '2018-01-01','2018-02-01'

A simpler option to get the same output (as suggested by @CharlesDuffy) is:

```
mystring="'$value1','$value2'"
```

Comment: I'd suggest `mystring="'$value1','$value2'"` instead -- easier to read without all the backslashes.

Answer (score 2):

You can just do like this, more simpler:

```
#!/bin/ksh -x
value1=2018-01-01
value2=2018-02-01

mystring=$value1,$value2
echo $mystring

stringify="'$value1','$value2'" #use double-quotes around the variables
echo $stringify
```

Output:

```
2018-01-01,2018-02-01
'2018-01-01','2018-02-01'
```